# Selected wrong activity to check in clearcase file ? How to move changes to correct activity?

Tags: clearcase, listactivity, clearcase-ucm

While check-in ClearCase file, I selected the wrong activity.

How to move changes to correct activity?

Answer (score 3):

You can select the properties of your version (for example through the version tree), open the activity properties, and in its "Change Set" tab, select the version of your checked-in file: a right-click on that line allows you to select "Move to" (and you chose another activity).

[image: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124923&aid=2]

See more at:

- "[To move versions to a different activity](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.dev.doc/topics/cc_dev/to_move_diff_activity.htm)"
- "[Moving an entry](https://www-304.ibm.com/connections/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.lotus.connections.activities.help%2Fw_oa_t_moving_an_entry.html)"
- "[Moving a UCM version in a change set from one activity to another](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124923)"

In command line, if you have the name of the activity:

> Change directory (cd) to the view that is associated with the stream which contains the change set and activity to be moved.

```
M:\test_proj1>cleartool lsact -long new
activity "new"
13-Jul-01.13:10:47 by username.cc_users@username_ntw
owner: username
group: CC_USERS
stream: test_proj1.9907@\test_pvob
title: new
change set versions:
M:\test_proj1\test_comp\dir1\mytext.txt@@\main\test_proj1.9907\1
M:\test_proj1\test_comp\dir1\hello.txt@@\main\test_proj1.9907\1

M:\test_proj1>cleartool chact -fcset new -tcset MOVED M:\test_proj1\test_comp\dir1\mytext.txt@@\main\test_proj1.9907\1
Moved version "M:\test_proj1\test_comp\dir1\mytext.txt@@\main\test_proj1.9907\1"
from activity "new" to activity "MOVED".
```